# Checking if every table object has a different name

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a Users table, each User has a identifier, a name and some other fields.
I need to check if there is another user with the same name after inserting or updating, so I made this trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER user_name
  BEFORE
  INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON Users
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  count INTEGER;
BEGIN
 SELECT COUNT(*) INTO count FROM Users WHERE name = :new.name AND idUser <> :new.idUser;
  IF count > 0
    THEN raise_application_error(-20007, 'There is already another user with the same name');
  END IF;
END;
```

It seems to work when inserting new users, but it doesn't when I update them, it looks like it "ignores" the idUser check so it always fails as it finds the same user with the same name.
Why is this happening? Thank you

Comment: Why aren't you using a `unique` constraint?

Comment: `create unique index uk_user_name on Users (name);` to solve all your problems

Comment: Yes, it works with the unique constraint/index, but I would like to know why it doesn't work this way.

Comment: Are you really sure you are getting `-20007, 'There is already another user with the same name'` error while updating ? I bet that the error is: `ORA-04091: table name is mutating, trigger/function may not see it`. You must to closely examine error messages.

Comment: First of all, you will get a compilation error with your Trigger as you have used `COUNT` as the variable name. You need to change that. Once you do that, your trigger code causes a mutating table error.

Comment: Get your trigger working "perfectly".  Then, have session #1 add user "A" without committing.  Then have session #2 add user "A" without committing.  Then commit both sessions.  That may help illustrate some of the reasons why using a `UNIQUE` constraint is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In triggers , there are 3 states as you know inserts update and delete , In update states there are new values and old values , I mean when you update a column you , you will replace the old value with new one , in trigger you can use the old and the new value of the column .. Please check this example

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER test001
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON tabletest001


DECLARE
      Operation       NUMBER;
      CustomerCode    CHAR(10 BYTE);
BEGIN


IF INSERTING THEN 
  Operation := 1;
  CustomerCode := :new.field1;
END IF;

IF UPDATING THEN 
  Operation := 2;
  CustomerCode := :old.field1;
END IF;    

// DO SOMETHING ...

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN ErrorCode := SQLCODE;

END;
/
```

in the above example , in update state I used old.value of the column , so in your example you should check the old value not new , please try it

```
if updating then 

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO count FROM Users WHERE name = :old.name AND idUser <> :old.idUser;
  IF count > 0
    THEN raise_application_error(-20007, 'There is already another user with the same name');

end if
```

however as in the comments adviced you is to use primary key, however my answer is to give you understanding to triggers